# #section vs section:nth-of-type(1) when Css selecting

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i´ve been told this but i wanted to confirm it.

Which is the fastest way to select in CSS from HTML?

```
<style>
#example{}

section div:nth-of-type(1){}
</style>
```

---

```
<body>
<section id="section">
    <div id="example">          

    </div> 

    <div id="example2">

    </div>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: you mean what by *fastest*? ... note that the 2nd selector will selector more than you think

Comment: if it's about specificity(or in other words, which rules will be applied), selecting with the `#`(hashtag or `ID` selector) has the highest specificity among other selectors.

Answer (score 2):

There are two important but counterintuitive principles to keep in mind when thinking about selector performance:

1. The rule-matching engine is designed on the assumption that there will be many more elements to be matched than rules to match against, and that only a few rules will apply to any given element.
2. The rule-matching engine does *not* walk the fully-constructed DOM tree from the root for each rule.  Rather, it walks the list of rules for each *element*, as it is parsed and added to the DOM.

Because of this, selector performance falls roughly into three categories.  If it's possible to decide whether or not a rule matches any given element by looking only at the element itself and its attributes -- not its contents or its relationship to other elements in the tree -- then matching will be very fast.  `#id`, `.class`, `tagname`, `[attr]`, etc selectors are all in this category.  The second most efficient category is when a decision can be made based only on the element and its parents, such as `#foo bar` or `.foo > .bar`.  These take time, in the worst case, proportional to the depth of the element in the DOM tree, which is usually not that large a number.  Everything else is slower, both because it involves more complicated DOM traversal, and because it hasn't been optimized as much in the implementation.

`#example` can be matched by looking only at the element itself, which is very fast.  But `div:nth-of-type(1)` requires walking the list of previous *siblings* of an element, which is inefficient.

Therefore, if what you were told was that `#example` is faster than `div:nth-of-type(1)` for the HTML and CSS fragment shown, then that was correct.  In a document this small it's not going to be a big deal, but in a large document with many `<div>` elements it might become a problem.

Comment: i just edited my error, check now.. i dont understand if omitting id in html make a web site faster, and selecting in CSS with element selectors and stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

- If you want that *specific* div to have the style, then use the ID selector (like `#example`)
- If you want the first `div` in **`#container`** to have the style, then use `#container div:first-of-type`.
- If you want **every `div` that is the first child of its parent**  to have the style, then use `div:first-of-type`.

Comment: your last sentence is not exactly true. `div:first-of-type` will select all the first divs inside the whold DOM

Comment: the second one is also not exactly true, because if we have many nested element we can also select many div. using this `#container`> div:first-of-type` will make the answer correct